# Angular-phonecat application no longer supported?

Tags: angularjs, git

I'm trying to work through the angular-phonecat tutorial, but the chapter checkouts (i.e. git checkout -f step-1) all fail with 'error: pathspec 'step-0' did not match any files known to git'. I did some searching on the error, a few responses said run a 'git fetch' first, but this did not help. Several other search results that I looked at had no answer. BTW, the git clone for the app did work. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Ugh, that tutorial probably hasn't been touched in a while, not to mention to code style is a bit outdated.  Although not a tutorial, this guide is a great start: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide  and there are plenty of other tutorials to look at as well.

Comment: I was kind of new to GIT at the time I had this problem. Turns out I left out the 'depth' in the clone command: `git clone --depth=16` ... I didn't realize I needed the 'depth' command. Lesson learned: follow the instructions.